# Python Gooey tighter layout

Tags: python

I have a python script where I use [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey).

Here is an example:

```
import argparse
from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser

@Gooey
def main(): 
    parser = GooeyParser()

    parser.add_argument('--arg1', dest='arg1', action='store_true', help='Here is a description of this argument')
    parser.set_defaults(arg1=True)

    parser.add_argument('--arg2', dest='arg2', action='store_true', help='Here is a description of this other argument')
    parser.set_defaults(arg1=True)

    parser.add_argument('--arg3', dest='arg3', action='store_true', help='Here is a description of yet another argument')
    parser.set_defaults(arg1=True)

    # ... etc

    parser.parse_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I have a LOT of boolean parameters. Right now each one of these shows up in the GUI like this:

```
[blank line]
arg_name
[blank line]
[CHECKBOX] Here is a description of this argument
[blank line]
```

Repeated over and over. This takes up a lot of space. Is there a way to condense all of these so I get:

```
[CHECKBOX] Here is a description of this argument
[CHECKBOX] Here is a description of this other argument
[CHECKBOX] Here is a description of yet another argument
...
```

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to generate the GUI?

Comment: Is this using Tkinter? If so, are they being placed by `.pack()`, `.grid()`, or `.place()`?? You need to give us more to work with

Comment: Just to confirm: when you say Gooey, you mean the [library by that name](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey), and not a humorous misspelling of the generic term "GUI", yes?

Comment: Kevin: Yes. Reedinationer: No, Gooey. Gooey may use Tkinter inside it though, I don't know. @Patrick: modifying the question now to include code.